# Passing a regex substitution as a variable in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to pass a regex substitution as a variable:

```
sub proc {
    my $pattern = shift;
    my $txt = "foo baz";

    $txt =~ $pattern;
}

my $pattern = 's/foo/bar/';
proc($pattern);
```

This, of course, doesn't work. I tried eval'ing the substitution:

```
eval("$txt =~ $pattern;");
```

but that didn't work either. What horribly obvious thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> I need to pass a regex substitution as a variable

Do you?  Why not pass a code reference?  Example:

```
sub modify
{
  my($text, $code) = @_;
  $code->($text);
  return $text;
}

my $new_text = modify('foo baz', sub { $_[0] =~ s/foo/bar/ });
```

In general, when you want to pass "something that does something" to a subroutine ("a regex substitution" in the case of your question) the answer is to pass a reference to a piece of code.  [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/) is a good book on the topic.

Comment: This worked, and is closest to what I had in mind. However, the resulting code is a bit funky and convoluted for my tastes, which I generally take as a hint that it's time to rethink my overall approach.

Comment: I'm new to Perl, so could you please explain what does the operator `->` do? What is the purpose of `$code->($text)`? Thanks.

Comment: The `->()` part dereferences $code as a code reference and executes it, passing the contents of the `()` as arguments. More here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References

Answer (score 8):

Well, you can precompile the regular expression using the *qr//* operator.  But you can't pass an operator (s///).

```
$pattern = qr/foo/;

print "match!\n" if $text =~ $pattern;
```

But if you have to pass the substitution operator, you are down to passing either code or strings:

```
proc('$text =~ s/foo/bar');

sub proc {
   my $code = shift;

   ...

   eval $code;
}
```

or, code:

```
proc(sub {my $text = shift;  $text =~ s/foo/bar});

sub proc {
   my $code = shift;

   ...

   $code->("some text");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
sub proc {
    my($match, $subst) = @_;
    my $txt = "foo baz";
    $txt =~ s/$match/$subst/;
    print "$txt\n";
}

my $matcher = qr/foo/;
my $sub_str = "bar";

proc($matcher, $sub_str);
```

This rather directly answers your question.  You can do more - but when I used a qr// term instead of the $sub_str as a simple literal, then the expanded regex was substituted.

I recently needed to create a parser (test parser) for statements with some peculiar (dialect of) SQL types, recognizing lines such as this, splitting it into three type names:

```
input: datetime year to second,decimal(16,6), integer
```

The script I used to demo this used quoted regexes.

```
#!/bin/perl -w
use strict;
while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    print "Read: <$_>\n";
    my($r1) = qr%^input\s*:\s*%i;
    if ($_ =~ $r1)
    {
        print "Found input:\n";
        s%$r1%%;
        print "Residue: <$_>\n";
        my($r3) = qr%(?:year|month|day|hour|minute|second|fraction(?:\([1-5]\))?)%;
        my($r2) = qr%
                        (?:\s*,?\s*)?   # Commas and spaces
                        (
                            (?:money|numeric|decimal)(?:\(\d+(?:,\d+)?\))?   |
                            int(?:eger)?  |
                            smallint      |
                            datetime\s+$r3\s+to\s+$r3
                        )
                    %ix;
        while ($_ =~ m/$r2/)
        {
            print "Got type: <$1>\n";
            s/$r2//;
        }
        print "Residue 2: <$_>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "No match:\n";
    }
    print "Next?\n";
}
```

We can argue about the use of names like $r1, etc.  But it did the job...it was not, and is not, production code.

Comment: What an ugly code and why you make regexp values again and again for every line?

Comment: It's demo code - which means 'not optimized' and 'not for production use'.  It was assembled to show that it works, and nothing else.

Answer (score 6):

`s///` is not a regex. Thus, you can't pass it as a regex.

I don't like `eval` for this. It's very fragile, with a lot of bordercases.

I think it's best to take an approach similar to the one JavaScript takes: pass both a regex (in Perl, that is `qr//`) and a code reference for the substitution. For example, to pass parameters to get the same effect as

```
s/(\w+)/\u\L$1/g;
```

You can call

```
replace($string, qr/(\w+)/, sub { "\u\L$1" }, 'g');
```

Note that the 'g' modifier is not actually a flag for the regex (I think attaching it to the regex is a design mistake in JavaScript), so I chose to pass it in a third parameter.

Once the API has been decided on, the implementation can be done next:

```
sub replace {
    my($string, $find, $replace, $global) = @_;
    unless($global) {
        $string =~ s($find){ $replace->() }e;
    } else {
        $string =~ s($find){ $replace->() }ge;
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Let's try it:

```
print replace('content-TYPE', qr/(\w+)/, sub { "\u\L$1" }, 'g');
```

Result:

> Content-Type

That looks good to me.

Comment: Data::Munge on CPAN has a 'replace' function similar to this, though it passes substring matches to the fuction, or parses the replacement as a string.

Answer (score 5):

```
eval "$txt =~ $pattern";
```

This becomes

```
eval "\"foo baz\" =~ s/foo/bar/"
```

and substitutions don't work on literal strings.

This would work:

```
eval "\$txt =~ $pattern"
```

but that's not very pleasing. *eval* is almost never the right solution.

[zigdon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125171/passing-a-regex-substitution-as-a-variable-in-perl/125212#125212) can do anything, and [Jonathan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125171/passing-a-regex-substitution-as-a-variable-in-perl/125240#125240) is quite suitable if the replacement string is static.  If you want something more structured than the first and more flexible than the second, I'd suggest a hybrid:

```
sub proc {
    my $pattern = shift;
    my $code = shift;
    my $txt = "foo baz";
    $txt =~ s/$pattern/$code->()/e;
    print "$txt\n";
}

my $pattern = qr/foo/;
proc($pattern, sub { "bar" });   # ==> bar baz
proc($pattern, sub { "\U$&" });  # ==> FOO baz
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you might rethink your approach.

You want to pass in to a function a regex substitution, probably because the function will be deriving the text to be operated upon from some other source (reading from a file, socket, etc.). But you're conflating regular expression with *regular expression substitution*.

In the expression, `s/foo/bar/`, you actually have a regular expression ("/foo/") and a substitution ("bar") that should replace what is matched by the expression. In the approaches you've tried thus far, you ran into problems trying to use `eval`, mainly because of the likelihood of special characters in the expression that either interfere with `eval` or get interpolated (i.e., gobbled up) in the process of evaluation.

So instead, try passing your routine two arguments: the expression and the substitution:

```
sub apply_regex {
    my $regex = shift;
    my $subst = shift || ''; # No subst string will mean matches are "deleted"

    # Some setup and processing happens...

    # Time to make use of the regex that was passed in:
    while (defined($_ = <$some_filehandle>)) {
        s/$regex/$subst/g; # You can decide if you want to use /g etc.
    }

    # The rest of the processing...
}
```

This approach has an added benefit: if your regex pattern *doesn't* have any special characters in it, you can just pass it in directly:

```
apply_regex('foo', 'bar');
```

Or, if it does, you can use the `qr//` quoting-operator to create a regex object and pass that as the first parameter:

```
apply_regex(qr{(foo|bar)}, 'baz');
apply_regex(qr/[ab]+/, '(one or more of "a" or "b")');
apply_regex(qr|\d+|); # Delete any sequences of digits
```

Most of all, you really don't need `eval` or the use of code-references/closures for this task. That will only add complexity that may make debugging harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I have an extremely simple script for mass file renaming that employs this trick:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl
sub oops { die "Usage : sednames s/old/new [files ..]\n"; }
oops if ($#ARGV < 0);

$regex = eval 'sub { $_ = $_[0]; ' . shift(@ARGV) . '; return $_; }';
sub regex_rename { foreach (<$_[0]>) {
    rename("$_", &$regex($_));
} }

if ($#ARGV < 0) {  regex_rename("*");  }
else {  regex_rename(@ARGV);  }
```

Any Perl command that modifies `$_` like `s/old/new` could be employed to modify the files.

I decided upon using `eval` so that the regular expression only needed to be compiled once.  There is some wonkiness with `eval` and `$_` that prevented me from using simply:

```
eval 'sub { ' . shift(@ARGV) . ' }';
```

Although this `&$regex` certainly does modify `$_`, requiring the `"$_"`  to evaluate `$_` before calling `rename`.  Yes, `eval` is quite fragile, like everyone else said.

Answer (score 0):

I found a probably better way to do it:

```perl
sub proc {
    my ($pattern, $replacement) = @_;
    my $txt = "foo baz";

    $txt =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/g;  # This substitution is global.
}

my $pattern = qr/foo/;  # qr means the regex is pre-compiled.
my $replacement = 'bar';

proc($pattern, $replacement);
```

If the flags of the substitution have to be variable, you can use this:

```
sub proc {
    my ($pattern, $replacement, $flags) = @_;
    my $txt = "foo baz";

    eval('$txt =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/' . $flags);
}

proc(qr/foo/, 'bar', 'g');
```

Please note that you don't need to escape `/` in the replacement string.

Comment: That may work with the particular input (fixed strings), but what if the pattern is "`(\w+)`" and the replacement is "`\u\L$1`"?

Answer (score -1):

You're right - you were very close:

```
eval('$txt =~ ' . "$pattern;");
```