# Is there a way to precompile a regex in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, compilation

Is there a way to precompile a regex in Perl? I have one that I use many times in a program and it does not change  between uses.

Comment: For the more general case of substitution, using variables containing the regular expressions and replacements (e.g., substitutions like `s/(\w+)/\u\L$1/g;` (in variables/external data), not just fixed strings in variables), see [bart's answer to *Passing a regex substitution as a variable in Perl*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125171/passing-a-regex-substitution-as-a-variable-in-perl/128321#128321)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

For literal (static) regexes there's nothing to do -- Perl will only compile them once.

```
if ($var =~ /foo|bar/) {
    # ...
}
```

For regexes stored in variables you have a couple of options. You can use the [`qr//`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) operator to build a regex object:

```
my $re = qr/foo|bar/;

if ($var =~ $re) {
    # ...
}
```

This is handy if you want to use a regex in multiple places or pass it to subroutines.

If the regex pattern is in a string, you can use the `/o` option to promise Perl that it will never change:

```
my $pattern = 'foo|bar';

if ($var =~ /$pattern/o) {
    # ...
}
```

It's usually better to not do that, though. Perl is smart enough to know that the variable hasn't changed and the regex doesn't need to be recompiled. Specifying `/o` is probably a premature micro-optimization. It's also a potential pitfall. If the variable *has* changed using `/o` would cause Perl to use the old regex anyway. That could lead to hard-to-diagnose bugs.

Comment: These are true; however, qr// has been supported for many years now (it's existed since 5.005, and I think there's been no issues with it since 5.8)

Comment: @ephemient Well, 5.10 has a nasty memory leak associated with qr// (and compiling regexes in general), but that has been fixed.  If you are using 5.10, you can check to see if you have the memory leak by saying perl -e 'qr// while 1'.  I know that the OS X version of ActiveState Perl 5.10 is still broken.

Comment: Note from 2016: the `/o` modifier has been deprecated.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/550258/477563) for details.

Comment: for multiple using the same precompiled regexp, you can use my $re = qr/foo|bar/ then next if ($var =~/something $re something/)   many times. It is docummented in perlre

Comment: I would suggest always measuring speed results. Never trust "it should be faster with precompiled stuff" feeling. For me, using `qr//` instead of just using regexps inline in code made it slower by more than 60% in perl 5.24.1 !

Answer (score 21):

Use the *qr//* operator (documented in *[perlop - Perl operators and precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)* under *[Regexp Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)*).

```
my $regex = qr/foo\d/;
$string =~ $regex;
```

Comment: nice, it seems that can be used as a pattern in the s/// construct. Is it still pre-compiled or is it compiled again in this case?

Comment: @akostadinov It is still pre-compiled.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, you can use a precompiled regex as:

```
my $re = qr/foo|bar/;  # Precompile phase
if ( $string =~ $re ) ...   # For direct use
if ( $string =~ /$re/ ) .... # The same as above, but a bit complicated
if ( $string =~ m/something $re other/x ) ...  # For use precompiled as a part of a bigger regex
if ( $string =~ s/$re/replacement/ ) ...  # For direct use as replace
if ( $string =~ s/some $re other/replacement/x ) ... # For use precompiled as a part of bigger regex, and as replace all at once
```

It is documented in [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre), but there are no direct examples.

Comment: I don't think "use precompiled as a part of bigger regex" is true. Regexes cannot be composed from strings. Eg consider what should happen if the next char after `$re` is `+`

Comment: it is dependend on implementation and flags used for regexp. only doing some benchmark and tests could show us what compiler really do. when regexp is hardly compiled, then changing $re value will give no effect. There will be used old $re value.