# Perl using match function with variable

Tags: regex, perl, match

How can i check match with variable and not with simple text.
i tried:

```
my $_text = 'Please Help me here!';
my $_searchingText = 'me';
if ($_text =~ $_searchingText) {
    print 'yes!';
}
```

Comment: you tried? and? It works for me!

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125171/passing-a-regex-substitution-as-a-variable-in-perl.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Interpolate `$_searchingText` in a regex pattern:

   ```
   print 'yes' if $_text =~ /$_searchingText/;
   ```
2. Declare `$_searchingText` as a pattern:

   ```
   $_searchingText = qr/me/;
   print 'yes' if $_text =~ $_searchingText;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the index function would do just what you're looking to do (which it seems is to "index" `$_searchingText` within `$_text`).

try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $_text = 'Please Help me here!';
my $_searchingText = 'me';

if(index $_searchingText, $_text){
    print 'yes!';
}
```

or you could put your variable to be matched (`$_searchingText`) within a regular expressions match operator:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $_text = 'Please Help me here!';
my $_searchingText = 'me';

if($_text =~ m/$_searchingText/){
    print 'yes!';
}
```

Hope that helps; Let me know if I can clarify

Comment: just tested it again; works in my terminal...

The index function searches for one string within another, but
               without the wildcard-like behavior of a full regular-expression
               pattern match.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you need to put the regular expression markers around your regular expression:

```
if ($_text =~ /$_searchingText/) {
```

and not

```
if ($_text =~ $_searchingText) {
```

---

Perl also can have a scalar Perl variable contain a regular expression and not just a string of characters or a number:

```
my $_text = 'Please Help me here!';
my $_searchingText = qr/me/;
if ($_text =~ $_searchingText) {
    print 'yes!';
}
```

The `qr` operator makes the value contained in `$_searchingText` a regular expression, so you don't need the separators in the `if` statement. They're optional. See [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).