# How to make Perl regex precompiled to save time during runtime

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Perl function as shown below, and it is taking a longer time to execute. (Note: This function is being called more than 10,000 times.)

After googling some, I found that **If I can precompile a Perl regex then the execution time may decrease.**

How can I modify a Perl regex so that it takes less time? Or is there a better solution?

```
sub some_func {
    my $var1=shift;
    my $var2=shift;

    if (!($var1 =~ /^UTF-?8$/)) {
         print "Do something important\n";
    }
    if ($var2 =~ /$some_global_string/i) {
         print "Do something important\n";
    }
}
```

E.g., $var2 can be

```
"character string with maximum 4096 character, Including html character as string"
```

and $some_global_string can be:

```
"string as $var2 but max length of 256 character"`
```

Comment: Please given an example of the content of `$var2` and `$some_global_string`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thanksfor the reply, I have edited the same details in question, Please have a look

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to precompile a regex in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952998/is-there-a-way-to-precompile-a-regex-in-perl)

Comment: The most general answer (also covers substitutions like `s/(\w+)/\u\L$1/g;` (in variables/external data), not just simple fixed strings in variables) is [bart's answer to *Passing a regex substitution as a variable in Perl*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125171/passing-a-regex-substitution-as-a-variable-in-perl/128321#128321)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators

```
my $RE1 = qr/^UTF-?8$/;
my $RE2 = qr/$some_global_string/i;
....
if ($var1 !~ /$RE1/) {...};
...
if ($var2 =~ /$RE2/) {...};
```

Comment: Thanks,
Can you please confirm, Is this $var1 !~ or $var1 =~       ??

Comment: That depends entirely on your use case @Chirag. It doesn't matter if you do a positive or negative match. The relevant info is that the `qr//` operator creates a pre-compiled pattern, and you'd do that in a larger scope or with `state`.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I just wanted to check if it was intentional or typo :)